# Order_by not functioning

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

i have this query but when the output displays its not sorted

```
function get_productbyid($productid) {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('projquotedetails,products')
                              ->where(array('projquotedetails.productid' => $productid))
                              ->where('projquotedetails.productid = products.productid')
                              ->order_by('page_order','asc')
                              ;

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { return $query->result_array(); }
        else                        { return 0; }

    }
```

Comment: Is `page_order` column exists in both tables?

Comment: no sir only in the projquotedetails table

Comment: did you try to see `$this->db->last_query();`?

Answer (score 1):

Query ::

```
     function get_productbyid($productid) {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('projquotedetails,products')
                          ->where(array('projquotedetails.productid' => $productid))
                          ->where('projquotedetails.productid = products.productid')
                          ->order_by('projquotedetails.page_order','asc')
                          ;

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { return $query->result_array(); }
    else                        { return 0; }

}
```